# Bypass Bean Validation during a select but not in insert/update

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 (JSF 2, JPA 2, EclipseLink, Bean Validation).

I'm trying to implement validation with the Bean Validation API with these annotations: `@Past`, `@Future` and `@NotNull`.

It works fine during insert or update. Unfortunately, when I try to select en entity which have some incorrect values, I have this exception:

```
[#|2011-12-20T10:18:30.286+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.preUpdate(BeanValidationListener.java:72)
```

I saw on the spec that I can disable JPA validation with this property `javax.persistence.ValidationMode` but **how to disable validation during select but NOT during insert or update**?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that anything in the persistence context will be validated.

You could avoid adding the objects to the persistence context, by reading them in a different EntityManager outside of a transaction, or use the "eclipselink.read-only" hint on the query reading them.

It does seem odd though that objects without changes are being validated.  If this is the case, then perhaps log a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Several comments.
First, the validation mode (*javax.persistence.validation.mode*) only determines the validation mode, auto, callback or none.

What you are after are the properties:

- *javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist*
- *javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update*
- *javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove*

which allow you to define for each of the main callbacks. None of these are related to selects though.

Looking at your error though, the *preUpdate* seems to fail. What and how exactly do you get this error?

Comment: EclipseLink is calling preUpdate on select it's a bug https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489191/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have similar issue with **Dates** in my application. I have **Transaction** entity and Term entity associated together and if **Transaction** gets old I am moving it to **Historical Transaction**. So I want that old **Terms** (Periods) stay in database, but also to prevent creation of new **Terms** with dates in the past. So **Terms** can only naturally getting older, and not be created as in the past by user. I consider whether using **@Future** on start/end dates of **Term** will work correctly.

This is hard to test it in app while developing, as I need to wait for **Term** to gets older and then move **Transaction** to **Historical Transaction**.